How do I read the color of cells in a range efficiently?
I have a range of 600 continuous cells in a column. I want to read the color of each cell in this range.
I can easily read the value of the cells in the range into an array using range.value which reads it all at once or at least I don't have to iterate over the entire 600 cells which will lead to frequent communication between excel and VBA and thus making it quite inefficient and time consuming.
But I'm unable to achieve efficient reading of color of cells. I have to loop through the entire 600 cells and use range.Interior.Color which is making the process quite slow.
I found a question asking the same problem and I found that one cannot retrieve the colors all at once like values but I want to know then how to retrieve them efficiently or correctly since looping over 600 or more cells takes time and I can see my worksheet lag  already.

There's been no change in the Range.Interior property object since the linked question in your post. So, sadly, looping over the range and checking each cell's color is your only option.

Why do you need to do this? Perhaps there are better approaches.

How are you looping over the cells? If you are selecting the cells, that will be slower versus simply referring to them.

@Rory I need to check through the entire range if the color of any cell matches a target color and do further processing if it matches. I thought to iterate over the cells in the range using range.cell(i, j).Interior.color but it is quite slow. I'm a beginner to using VBA in excel.

@PeterConstable I use for each loop and use range.cells(i,j).Interior.color

My question was more why do you need to use colour? Pretty much any time you are doing that in Excel, it's not a good idea. Colours should reflect data, not be data. If you are stuck with colour, then you are stuck with looping.

You pressed upon important point. I think I was very hardly focused on color. I need to make changes to my excel layout. Thank you very much

How is the colour of the cells generated? If by conditional formatting, use that same test to determine which cells to process.

Reading Interior.Color from 10,000 cells takes about 0.05 sec on my PC.  Is that really "slow"?  Possibly the slow-down exists somewhere else in your code.

@TimWilliams You are right. I found the problem in my case and why it was taking around 2.7 seconds. Actually I created a 600x70 excel  sheet and I did lots and lost of referencing among cells. A particular group of cells were linked to around 300 cells directly/indirectly which was resulting in calling the looping function for checking color multiple times (around 250-300 times). This was the real trouble. I did my research and I'm further improving upon recalculating only specific cells and baring others from recalculating automatically. Thank you so much.

If you want to find cells with a specific color in a given range, you can use the Find method with a format pattern. This is the scheme of the code: rng is the range you want to look in, cell D1 is the color pattern. The result is a found range that includes all found cells of the given color. If the What parameter of the Find method is set to empty text, all cells of the specified color will be found, regardless of their contents.
Sub FindFormattedCells()
    Dim rng As Range, adr As String
    Dim found As Range, newf As Range
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .Color = Range("D1").Interior.Color         ' color pattern
    End With
    Set rng = Range("A1:A20")    ' where to find
    Set found = rng.Find(What:="", SearchFormat:=True)
    If found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    adr = found.Address
    Set newf = found
    Do
        Set newf = rng.Find(What:="", After:=newf, SearchFormat:=True)
        Set found = Union(found, newf)
    Loop Until newf.Address = adr
    Debug.Print found.Address
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
End Sub

